# How to get downloadUrl firebase storage with firebase admin sdk and put in img html's tag in nodejs with multer?

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-storage, nuxt.js

I am building the image upload system. I want to use the Firebase Admin sdk for handling this process. How to get the url to store in my Google Cloud Storage and fetch them on display in img tag (html) when the uploading is completed.

```
try {
    const file = req.file;
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
    const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(file.buffer, "base64");
    const imageByteArray = new Uint8Array(imageBuffer);
    const options = {
      resumable: false,
      metadata: { contentType: file.mimetype },
      predefinedAcl: "publicRead",
      public: true,
    };
    const files = bucket.file(`img/${file.originalname}`);
    await files.save(imageByteArray, options);
    const field = await files.getMetadata();
    console.log(field);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
```

Comment: Hi, May I know which url are you talking about? And also can you please explain in brief about your code, like what are you doing or trying to do and what is expected but what is happening instead etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Node.js Admin SDK you should do as follows, using the [`getSignedUrl()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#getSignedUrl) method:

```
const { initializeApp, cert } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getStorage } = require('firebase-admin/storage');

const serviceAccount = require('./path/to/serviceAccountKey.json');

initializeApp({
  credential: cert(serviceAccount),
  storageBucket: '<BUCKET_NAME>.appspot.com'
});


// ...

async function getSignedURL(fileName) {
    const bucket = getStorage().bucket();
    // Or const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(); like you do in your question, depending on where and how you execute the code
    const file = bucket.file(fileName);

    const signedURLconfig = { action: 'read', expires: '01-01-2030' };
    // See more options of the config object in the SDK documentation (link above)

    const signedURLArray = await file.getSignedUrl(signedURLconfig);
    return signedURLArray[0];
}


// Use the above function to save the signed URL to Firestore
const fileName = "...";
getSignedURL(fileName)
.then(signedURL => {
    admin.firestore().collection("urls_collection")
    .add({url: signedURL, foo: "bar", bar: "foo"})
});
```

Comment: And , then how get in public url and store to the database?

Comment: Just call the asynchronous getSignedURL method and write a Firestore document containing the returned value, see the update.

Comment: oh , wow thank you very muchh 

Comment: @RenaudTarnec `signedUrl` doesn't work after few days. Is there any way to generate long lived url using cloud functions?

Comment: Please note that signedUrls expire after a period of time and it seems google is not providing an easy way of doing this.
There's a huge discussion about this happening here: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/697

Comment: Yes signedURLs expire after a certain period of times. You can use set of scheduled Cloud Functions to update them regularly.